# Rails: passing parameters from bootstrap-modal link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, parameters, link-to

I have the modal launch button as:

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal">View Details</a>
```

and I made it to work with link_to:

```
<%=link_to "View Details",'#myModal',class: "btn btn-success",data: {toggle: "modal"} %>
```

But I want to pass some parameters like:

```
<%=link_to "View Details",'#myModal',{controller: :mycontroller,action: :myaction,foo: :bar},class: "btn btn-success",data: {toggle: "modal"} %>
```

Which I can access in my `Mycontroller`'s `myaction`. But the above method gives me nil as the value of 'foo`.

How to pass params in this case?

Or is there a way to **make a `path_helper` for `#myModal`** so I can pass params easily. Like:

> path "/modal" => "#myModal"

So that I can access it like:

> modal_path(foo: "bar")

**EDIT**

I **tried** this:

```
<%=link_to "View Details","#myModal?famid="+family.famid,class: "btn btn-success",data: {toggle: "modal"} %>
```

and in **controller action**:

```
@fam=Family.find_by(famid: params[:famid])
```

But that gives:

> Document not found for class Family with attributes {:famid=>nil}

Comment: Why do you want to pass parameters via the link? Your link code suggests you're rendering the Modal on the same page as the link. Therefore just render the variables directly in the Modal.

Comment: nope my modal is on another page than the link

Comment: But, your destination in the link_to syntax is being specified as '#myModal'. Do you have JS that picks that up and loads the correct page for you?

Comment: ohk. If you know `gamps4rails` my link is in the `infowindow` partial and `modal` is in the `map` views. Simply lets just say that I want to pass params from the modal link. see the **updated question**

Comment: But they're displayed in the same browser page at the same time?

Comment: The link is displayed in the google maps `infowindows' and the `modal` in `map.html.erb`. both the infowindow and modal are in the `map.html.erb`. But still it is different if u happen to know Gmaps4rails.

Comment: Try `family.id` rather than `family.famid`

Comment: @BetjaminRichards no luck with id too!

Comment: Can you post what you get in the logs when you click the link `<%=link_to "View Details","#myModal?famid="+family.famid,class: "btn btn-success",data: {toggle: "modal"} %>`

Comment: `Request parameters {"controller"=>"managedb", "action"=>"map"}`    When I click on the `View Details` button I do se `http://localhost:3000/map#myModal?famid=FID13801777421604` in url.Which means `famid` is being passed without any errors.

Comment: The '#' in your URL is likely causing the problem, not allowing rails to understand that it is a parameter.

Comment: but that is how it works. the link directs it to another div. so the `#` of `id` is there.

Comment: You can use `data-target="#myModal"` instead of `href="#myModal"`:

Comment: by that can I pass the params